# Declare javascript object property issue

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to declare a `javascript` `object properties`.

I have

```
  var myObj = {};
    var rowsCount, columnsCount, texts;
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = tableData;  //tableData is bunch of tables in html

    var tables = temp.getElementsByTagName('table')

    //use tables as array...
    for(var i = 0; i<tables.length; i++){
        var table = tables[i];
        myObj.rowsCount = $('tr', table).length;
        myObj.columnsCount = $('td', table).length / myObj.rowsCount;
    }
```

The above codes work. However, if I remove

```
 var rowsCount, columnsCount, texts;
```

the code will complain `rowsCount, columnsCount` and `texts` are not defined.

However, in W3Cschool `object` page, they have

```
person=new Object();
person.firstname="John";
person.lastname="Doe";
person.age=50;
person.eyecolor="blue";
```

and it seems fine without declaring the property first.

Can someone help me out here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: -1, can't replicate. Just pasted this code into the Chrome console, with `tableData` set to some random string and `var rowsCount, columnsCount, texts;` commented out, and... no error. Don't see any reason why there should be an error either. Presumably your problem is outside your pasted code.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the code will complain*"? Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myObj.rowsCount` is not the same as the `rowsCount` *variable*. The first is a property of an object, the other one is just a variable (with the same name).

If you're getting that error (assuming it's a ReferenceError), it's because you're trying to read from the `rowsCount` variable (not `myObj.rowsCount`) when it doesn't exist. That must be happening in some part of your code that you didn't show us.

Comment: understood. I just realize the problem is somewhere else. I really need to go to bed now.....Thanks!